# Can't get SRC out of inner html/DIV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to extract multiple audio PHP SRC links from a page for my script, so I wrote a script in jQuery for it:

**The script itself:**

```
 var irl=[];
$('.wave').each(function(){
    irl.push($(this).find('.content a audio').first().attr('src'));
});
```

**The DIV where I need the SRC from:**

```
<div class="wave" id="wave264157">
    <div class="wave-loader"></div>
    <wave style="display: block; position: relative; user-select: none; height: 52px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 1;">
        <wave style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 0px; display: block; box-sizing: border-box; border-right: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);">
        </wave>
    </wave>
    <audio preload="auto" src="/streamers/play.php?id=1503679495.2466:4f50ea025057d05c466e9257b3c801d79fe94f94:af9a240e2c688feede97706c401896a9475811e5e7452da7b65f5601fcca9dff8aa75b73769a7023d9342533cbd213ccf7a3094e562451c23c8e85c1c978254c14bae30b1a8bb58854bf3d34b0c63b71aff613ab92bea9f21feef8f320e9b34b48f5e0072e747624e1a3a60fb3a064a7bfe323481b2787d9ae3f455f31314a7276495c2e405103cedbe09982a246e6a8a0e96cb32a122fb3ac710a4608fad2f305688fdec15d9bb0a4edb0da1cffe91191041947a59f64b6c85e04382400943559ff5570004bb8006575838759774a5dc47a45da6c5d119344a569cb885f2f0f" 
style="width: 100%;">
    </audio>
</div>
```

But it did not give me the desired output, instead it [gave me the whole DIV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eQgk.png) information set (correct me if I'm wrong), but the sourcelink is also in the 'innerHTML' of this output. So maybe I can extract it form here?

Also all the classes of the diffrent SRC links on the page are "wave" and the id's are also all called "wave*****" where the '*****' is a random number that can be between 1 and 1000000.

Comment: There's no element under the wave divs with a class name of content ....

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any anchors either ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is just one audio per `.wave` div then you could this:

```
var irl=[];
$('.wave').each(function(){
    irl.push($(this).find('audio').attr('src'));
});
```

if you have more than one audio per `.wave` div then you could do something like this:

```
var irl=[];
$('.wave').each(function(){
        $(this).find('audio').each(function(){
        irl.push($(this).attr('src'))
    })
});
```

Comment: Since he's using `.first()` it seems like he doesn't want all of them.